# Computer freezes and stutters when playing games

Tags: windows-7, memory, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

My computer whenever playing games begin to freeze and then begins to stutter. The sounds comes out of the headset, not the case. I thought it might be the PSU, so i changed the PSU. Thought it might be the GPU, so i change the GPU. I then reinstalled windows and installed a game, it did it again. I then thought it was the CPU temps and bought pre-made liquid cooling, still does it.

Specs

- i5 4590s on MSI Mobo b85m-e45 (ms-7817)
- 16 gig ddr3
- 970 GTX, G1
- 500 gig samsung ssd.
- EDIT: 1000 watt PSU
- Win7 64bit

I honestly don't know what to do anymore. I don't know what is wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: Are all your drivers up-to-date? Have you tried to monitor the CPU/RAM using task manager when this is happening? Do they max out? There are many basic troubleshooting steps to go through before replacing hardware components.

Comment: Try removing ram, cleaning it and reinstalling......

Answer (score 0):

Update your video graphics driver as I strongly believe that it might be the suspect. BTW, which games you are playing specifically when this happens?

I'd also recommend to ask on their specific community if this happens with only any particular game.

Good luck!!